# Binding Chef-server 12 to specific IP address: Connection refused connecting to https://127.0.0.1/users/, retry 1/5

Tags: chef-infra

We have multiple applications running on the same server but on a different IPs (192.168.50.130:443 applicationA, 192.168.50.131:443 applicationB and so on)

We wanted to install chef server on the same machine. By default chef server's nginx listens on all IP address (0.0.0.0:443 and 0.0.0.0:80). As we had other application running on the same port 443, Chef couldn't bind its default ip address (0.0.0.0) to the port 443. So we changed the chef's nginx cookbooks to bind to a specific ip address. Now that we have chef server's nginx running on specific ip, 192.168.56.137:443. Just so you know we were also successfully able bring up chef.example.ca on a browser after changing it to a specific ip address.

The issue really is when we tried to create users using chef-server-ctl create-user command. We get the following error.

```
chef-server-ctl user-create user_name first_name last_name email password --filename FILE_NAME
```

Getting the error 5 times and message saying it gives up.

```
ERROR: Connection refused connecting to https://127.0.0.1/users/, retry 1/5
```

Here is my /etc/opscode/chef-server.rb

```
server_name = "chef.example.ca"
api_fqdn = server_name
notification_email = "NO-REPLY-CHEF@example.ca"

#######################
# nginx configuration #
#######################
nginx['url'] = "https://#{server_name}"
nginx['server_name'] = server_name
#nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/nginx-certs/chef/chef.example.ca.crt"
#nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/nginx-certs/chef/chef.example.ca.key"
#nginx['ssl_protocols'] = "TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2"
```

/etc/hosts file:

```
  192.168.56.137 chef.example.ca
```

Could you please help me understand why chef is still looking to connect via localhost (127.0.0.1) while the configuration for server_name and api_fqdn is "chef.example.ca". Also can this ip address be changed to 192.168.56.137? Thank you!

---

After changing the chef's nginx cookbook. I was able to enforce chef server to listen to on a specific ip address like I wanted.

```
 # default behavior to listen only on v4
      "listen  "+  node['private_chef']['nginx']['server_name'] +":#{listen_port};"
```

But when I tried to login into the web gui, I get the following error
[image]

---

```
Chef-manage-ctl tail
```

---

```
2016-04-14_14:07:36.98112 I, [2016-04-14T11:07:36.974593 #51397]  INFO -- : Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-14 11:07:36 -0300
2016-04-14_14:07:37.07912 I, [2016-04-14T11:07:37.077410 #51397]  INFO -- : Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
2016-04-14_14:07:37.40107 I, [2016-04-14T11:07:37.397369 #51397]  INFO -- :   Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/outside (171.2ms)
2016-04-14_14:07:37.43189 I, [2016-04-14T11:07:37.428147 #51397]  INFO -- :   Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (2.4ms)
2016-04-14_14:07:37.44882 I, [2016-04-14T11:07:37.447813 #51397]  INFO -- :   Rendered shared/_footer.html.haml (4.6ms)
2016-04-14_14:07:37.47773 I, [2016-04-14T11:07:37.476979 #51397]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_client_config.html.erb (2.1ms)
2016-04-14_14:07:37.47985 I, [2016-04-14T11:07:37.479065 #51397]  INFO -- :   Rendered shared/_js.html.erb (0.9ms)
2016-04-14_14:07:37.48226 I, [2016-04-14T11:07:37.480695 #51397]  INFO -- :   Rendered shared/_marketo.html.erb (0.5ms)
2016-04-14_14:07:37.48230 I, [2016-04-14T11:07:37.481110 #51397]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 404ms (Views: 397.9ms)
2016-04-14_14:07:43.69537 I, [2016-04-14T11:07:43.691233 #51397]  INFO -- : Started POST "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-14 11:07:43 -0300
2016-04-14_14:07:43.69540 I, [2016-04-14T11:07:43.692915 #51397]  INFO -- : Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
2016-04-14_14:07:43.69541 I, [2016-04-14T11:07:43.692999 #51397]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ZF7NM8/Rtr+ObtRxdUZcIQfSohbaKYtGi751bHbm/HkHfGejnQ1peCG+lFXuHYsFS5e/OS6HtxZnU+rC5d+qgw==", "to"=>"", "username"=>"srinivd1", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Sign In"}
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95797 E, [2016-04-14T11:07:43.956971 #51397] ERROR -- : Connection refused - Connection refused connecting to https://localhost:444/authenticate_user, giving up
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95799 E, [2016-04-14T11:07:43.957083 #51397] ERROR -- : /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/chef-11.16.2/lib/chef/http.rb:305:in `rescue in retrying_http_errors'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95799 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/chef-11.16.2/lib/chef/http.rb:291:in `retrying_http_errors'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95800 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/chef-11.16.2/lib/chef/http.rb:256:in `send_http_request'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95800 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/chef-11.16.2/lib/chef/http.rb:143:in `request'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95800 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/chef-11.16.2/lib/chef/http.rb:126:in `post'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95800 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/chef-manage/app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:86:in `authenticate'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95800 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/chef-manage/app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:27:in `create'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95800 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95801 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95801 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95801 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95802 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95802 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95802 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95802 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95802 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95803 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95804 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95804 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95804 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95804 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95804 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95805 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95805 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95805 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95805 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95806 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95806 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95806 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.5.2/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95806 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95806 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95807 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95807 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `call'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95807 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95807 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95807 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95807 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95808 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95808 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:815:in `call'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95808 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95808 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95809 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95809 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95809 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95809 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95809 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95810 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95810 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95810 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95810 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95811 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95811 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95811 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95811 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95811 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95812 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95812 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:22:in `call'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95812 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95812 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95812 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95812 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95813 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95813 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95813 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/ssl.rb:24:in `call'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95813 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sentry-raven-0.15.1/lib/raven/integrations/rack.rb:54:in `call'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95814 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95814 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95814 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95814 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95814 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:580:in `process_client'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95814 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-worker-killer-0.4.3/lib/unicorn/worker_killer.rb:52:in `process_client'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95815 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-worker-killer-0.4.3/lib/unicorn/worker_killer.rb:92:in `process_client'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95815 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:674:in `worker_loop'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95815 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:529:in `spawn_missing_workers'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95816 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:140:in `start'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95816 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95816 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
2016-04-14_14:07:43.95816 /opt/chef-manage/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.2.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
2016-04-14_14:07:44.02026 I, [2016-04-14T11:07:44.016528 #51397]  INFO -- :   Rendered errors/error_500.haml within layouts/outside (2.0ms)
2016-04-14_14:07:44.02028 I, [2016-04-14T11:07:44.018118 #51397]  INFO -- :   Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (0.4ms)
2016-04-14_14:07:44.02029 I, [2016-04-14T11:07:44.018601 #51397]  INFO -- :   Rendered shared/_footer.html.haml (0.3ms)
2016-04-14_14:07:44.02029 I, [2016-04-14T11:07:44.019163 #51397]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_client_config.html.erb (0.4ms)
2016-04-14_14:07:44.02029 I, [2016-04-14T11:07:44.019458 #51397]  INFO -- :   Rendered shared/_js.html.erb (0.1ms)
2016-04-14_14:07:44.02029 I, [2016-04-14T11:07:44.019674 #51397]  INFO -- :   Rendered shared/_marketo.html.erb (0.1ms)
2016-04-14_14:07:44.02029 I, [2016-04-14T11:07:44.019874 #51397]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 327ms (Views: 5.9ms)
```

Comment: You should **not** change the internal chef cookbook, there's a configuration file name `chef-server.rb` to fine tune chef-server install and reconfigure tools accordingly. [Documentation here](https://docs.chef.io/server_tuning.html)

Comment: Yeah I have seen that documentation. Unfortunately there is no configuration to tune nginx's 443 and 80 listening port!

Comment: check the chef-server-running.json file in /etc/opscode you'll find the proper values. You didn't say if you had run chef-server-ctl reconfigure after changing the. Rb file (sorry for the formatting, typing on phone)

Comment: All settings here: https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_server_optional_settings.html

Comment: @Tensibai - I've seen this documentation. Could you be more specific on what I should changes? :)

Comment: more or less every 'external' urls,  from memory (at home actually) I can't tell. I'll post what I have tomorow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after some digging and checks, there's no native way to restrict the IP on which nginx is listening, so the best way would be to use another port.

As your original problem is the SSL port, a supported way to have chef next another web server using 443 is to change nginx ssl port (from [The documentation](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_server_optional_settings.html#nginx) with this kind of chef-server.rb configuration:

```
nginx['ssl_port']=444
```

Then you have to configure your clients accordingly to use the correct port when you give them the chef-server url.

**Reminder**: after any change in `chef-server.rb` you have to run `chef-server-ctl reconfigure` to update services configuration and command line tools.

---

If you're wondering why restrincting on a specific IP is not supported, here's the results of my digging in the code with an amended chef-server.rb which should work at end **I highly discourage this use**, it will broke at every update unless a pull request is made to change this behavior:

The root cause is [this line](https://github.com/chef/chef-server/blob/master/omnibus/files/private-chef-cookbooks/private-chef/libraries/nginx_erb.rb#L55) in the nginx erb helper used by the `nginx_chef_api_lb.conf.erb` template.

```
  # default behavior to listen only on v4
  "listen #{listen_port};"
```

So you have to modify the private-chef cookbook to make it listen on a specific IP, it may worth a PR to include the `lb['vip']` as part of the template. (Side note: I had swear it was already used this way)

Then for everything to work properly from the outside, nginx should now what the server is, using api_fqdn should be enough as all other attributes takes this value if they're not set (excerpt from [here](https://github.com/chef/chef-server/blob/master/omnibus/files/private-chef-cookbooks/private-chef/libraries/private_chef.rb#L427-L432):

```
def gen_api_fqdn_default
  PrivateChef["lb"]["api_fqdn"] ||= PrivateChef['api_fqdn']
  PrivateChef["lb"]["web_ui_fqdn"] ||= PrivateChef['api_fqdn']
  PrivateChef["nginx"]["server_name"] ||= PrivateChef['api_fqdn']
  PrivateChef["nginx"]["url"] ||= "https://#{PrivateChef['api_fqdn']}"
end
```

but then there's the `chef-server-ctl` configuration (namely `pivotal.rb`) which takes the `lb['vip']` value and not the `api_fqdn` value.

So a working `chef-server.rb` file may be:

```
api_fqdn = "chef.example.ca"
lb['vip'] = server_name
notification_email = "NO-REPLY-CHEF@example.ca"
```

Comment: @dinesh there's a nginx['non_ssl_port'] too, but you can simply disable non_ssl port, see the documentation link and have a look at all nginx parameters,  you''ll find them

Comment: Hey, having chef running on different SSL port (444) does prevents the conflict with other applications. and I also had to change the non_ssl port as well. And I also tried the not recommended method as well. 

I changed the following line in the chef's cookbook to make chef listen on a specific ip address.
`
# default behavior to listen only on v4
  "listen  "+  node['private_chef']['nginx']['server_name'] +":#{listen_port};"
`
But after changing this, I am not able to login in the Chef manage console from the browser I get the following error.

`
500
Smell something burning?
`

Comment: @Dinesh I'm unsure I get you, is your original problem solved by changing both ports ? The other way is a ugly hack, I don't have all version of chef server to test so it can break something somewhere indeed.

Comment: The proper writing of adding the vip should be `"listen #{node['private_chef']['lb']['vip']}:#{listen_port};"`

Comment: @Dinesh upadted my answer, dunno why I didn't check again, serer_name is nothing existing as parameter (nginx['server_name'] is). should be better this way.

Comment: Yes changing the port numbers solved the conflict issues. But now I have to have the port number in the url - https://chef.example.ca:444.

Comment: But want to see if the ugly way would work for me because i dont like having port numbers in the url. Having said, by using the ugly approach Now I am not able to login into the web gui application I am getting an 500 error. I have updated my question with error (please have take look at my updated description).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109178/discussion-between-dinesh-and-tensibai).

Answer (score 1):

I think setting you want is `lb['vip'] = 'whatever'`. That said, Chef Server is an appliance and expects to control the box entirely. You shouldn't run it on the same machine as other services. Either put it in its own VM or use something like LXC/D to lock it in a container.

Comment: changing lb's vip didn't work. yeah I understand chef recommends installing on a fresh/separate machine. But we wanted to try if we can get it installed on the existing machine. Getting a new machine is a bit of a hassle.

Comment: You don't need a new machine to use LXC.

Comment: Also what do you mean by "didn't work"? That config option is used to generate the `/etc/opscode/pivotal.rb` config file, double check that it looks correct in there. That config file is in turn used by `chef-server-ctl`.

Comment: are you able to send me some tutorial on how to setup LXC on Centos?

Comment: oh wait a min. After restarting the machine, It worked. I'm now able to create the users using the chef-server-ctl user-create command. 
/etc/opscode/pivotal.rb
`node_name "pivotal"
chef_server_url "https://chef.example.ca:443"
chef_server_root "https://chef.example.ca:443"
no_proxy "chef.example.ca"
client_key "/etc/opscode/pivotal.pem"
ssl_verify_mode :verify_none`

Comment: However, I am not able to login via chef management console (gui interface). Any idea on that?

Comment: @Dinesh you'll have some other parameters to tweak along this one, I'll post my conf as answer tomorow (server running on virtual Ip for a dirty HA configuration,  to use at your own risks, you'd better follow coderanger advices and look for lxc/docker tutorials)

Comment: @Tensibai, I would like to give it a shot with your configuration first. If you could send me a detailed answer that would be great. :) If that doesn't work then. I would probably get it installed on a LXC or on a separate machine entirely. Thanks for your help!